# Unable to open hello.html in the same Jquery UI tab. I always get navigated to other browser tabs... I want it to be displyed in the 1st tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, tabs

```
<!-- this is the script-->
```

```js
 $(function() { 
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
```

```html
<div id="tabs">
<ul> 
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Bus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Hotel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Trip</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>This is tab 1 </p>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>This is tab 2 </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>This is tab 3 </p>
    </div>

   </div>
   </body>
```

Unable to open hello.html in the same Jquery UI tab. I always get navigated to other browser tabs... I want it to be displyed in the 1st tab..

Comment: where is `hello.html` and how is it used

Comment: it's just a normal .html file... placed in the same folder... it just prints "hello" nothing else.. basically i wanna show "hello" in the 1st tab...